# how to create EditText using for loop in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanna create a `EditText` in `TableLayout` in such a way by getting number of rows and columns i.e if rows is 4 and column is 3 then i need 12 `EditText` fields.Just give me an idea...

Answer (score 1):

I guess that example would help you from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- edittext span 2 column -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="Column 1 &amp; 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- just draw a red line -->
    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <!-- 3 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- display this button in 3rd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- display this button in 2nd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir.How can i do the same by java program by getting no. of rows and columns from the user.I need only " editext "..

Comment: see the example from there http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html

Comment: accepted sir!!sir will you help me if i have any doubt

Comment: yaeh sure , post your quewstiomn , here i'll help! :) with pleasure.. :)